# I want to install PHP plugin at Netbeans

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, netbeans-7

I want to install PHP plugin at Netbeans  . I click on Tool --> plugin --> Available Plugins But there is no plugin list available [image]

please tell me how to install php plugin at netbeans at ubuntu 14.04

Comment: how to update , give me command

Comment: In netbeans go to `help->check update` or download new 1

Answer (score 2):

**First of all you need internet connection while installing PHP plugins on netbeans. After connect to internet you need to use following steps-**

Steps

```
1. open netbeans and click on Tools > Plugins
2. plugins screen will be displayed 
3. click on Available Plugins tab and choose PHP.
4.click Next to continue
5. tick on I accept the terms in all of the license agreements checkbox.
6. installing the plugin
7. after finished, restart the program
8. click File > New Project and choose PHP project
9. define Name and Location of the project
10. click Finish to proceed
11. your php project has been created
12. write a simple coding to test your project whether it works or not
13. finish.
```

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Same issue i have faced

i click  (Reload Catalog) button inside of you showed one popup called plugin

if you click that button it will automatically show all the available plugin there you can see php relates plugin then select and install

i hope this is helpful for you